# Simulate Missing Data Mechanism MAR (and MNAR)

Tags: r, simulation, missing-data

)
I am trying to simulate the three MD-Mechanisms MCAR, MAR and MNAR. MCAR was fairly easy. 
For MNAR I simulated 10% missing data (MD) which are lying above the median of my variable "Wind" (I'm thinking about extending it to split for example 7% MD above and 3% below the median but I'm not quite done yet). 
My problem now is to find the corresponding MAR Mechanism. I know what it is but I dont really know how to approach it. 
I would really appreciate your help!

```
    ##### generic data setup:
data <- na.omit(airquality)

# MCAR - fertig
prop.m = .1  # 10% missingness
mcar   = runif(length(data[,1]), min=0, max=1)
Wind.mcar = ifelse(mcar<prop.m, NA, data$Wind)
data_mcar <- cbind(subset(data, select = -c(Wind)), Wind.mcar)

#MNAR
data_nmar <- data
higher <- data_nmar$Wind[data_nmar$Wind > median(data_nmar$Wind)]
# lower <- data_nmar$Wind[data_nmar$Wind <= median(data_nmar$Wind)]
data_nmar$Wind[data_nmar$Wind > median(data_nmar$Wind)] = ifelse(sample(c(T, F), length(data_nmar$Wind[data_nmar$Wind > median(data_nmar$Wind)]), replace=T, prob=c(0.1, 0.9)), NA, data_nmar$Wind[data_nmar$Wind > median(data_nmar$Wind)])
```

Comment: Essentially you will index missingness to some other variable or set of variables in a given data set. So if the missingness is on the variable `Wind`, you would condition missingness on the values of some other variable in your data set.

Comment: Hi Matt,
thank you for your answer. That already helped me to get on the right track!